# Create dynamic file reference

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet in which there are two columns (actually a *lot* more columns but two for simplicity):

```
      A        B
1    Name     File
2    AAA      = 'file:///Data/AAA.ods'#$Sheet1.A10
3    BBB      = 'file:///Data/BBB.ods'#$Sheet1.A10
4    CCC      = 'file:///Data/CCC.ods'#$Sheet1.A10
```

Rather than hardcoding the URL in the second column, I would like to use the value in the Name field (say 'AAA') to create the value in the corresponding File field.

For example, the cell B2 would have a formula in the sense of:

```
= 'file:///Data/[A2].ods'#$Sheet1.A10
```

which would give the same result had I hard coded the full URL.

Is there are way to get the URL in the second column to be constructed using the value from the (corresponding) first column?

All I can manage is to get the text value of the URL to appear, but not the actual URL (which then retrieves the external data).

Thanks in advance,

Bernmeister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT):

```
=INDIRECT("'file:///Data/" & A2 & ".ods'#$Sheet1.A10")
```

Comment: Thanks - all too easy!